# Show that a group is isomorphic to it's semidirect product.

Tags: group-theory

K is a group with two subgroups, G and H with the following properties:

G is normal in K.

$G\cap H = \{e\}$

$\forall k\in K$, k can be written as gh, for some $g\in G$ and $h\in H$.

How to show that K is isomorphic to the semidirect group $G\rtimes H$, where
H acts on G by the inner autmorphisms of K restricted to G?

Comment: @Donantonio Yeah, thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since for any $\;k\;$ we have that $\;k=g_kh_k\;,\;\;g_k\in G\;,\;\;h_k\in H\;$ , define

$$\Phi: K\to G\rtimes H\;,\;\;\Phi k:=(g_k,\,h_k)$$

Observe that

$$k=g_kh_k=g'_kh'_k\implies g_k^{-1}g'_k=h'_kh_k^{-1}\in G\cap K=1$$

so the expression $\;k=g_kh_k\;$ is *unique* and $\;\Phi\;$ is thus a well defined map.

Show now that $\;\Phi\;$ is a group homomorphism: $\;\Phi(kx)=\Phi k\,\Phi x\;$ , but:

$$\begin{cases}k=g_kh_k\\{}\\x=g_xh_x\end{cases}\;\implies kx=g_kh_kg_xh_x=g_k\left(h_kg_xh_k^{-1}\right)\left(h_kh_x\right)\stackrel{\Phi}\mapsto\left(\,g_k\left(h_kg_xh_k^{-1}\right)\,,\,h_kh_x\,\right)$$

whereas

$$\Phi k\,\Phi x:=(g_k,\,h_k)(g_x,\,h_x)\stackrel{\text{def. of sem. prod}}=\left(g_k\,g_x^{h_k}\,,\,\,h_kh_x\right)$$

and thus we're done (why? What does $\;g_x^{h_k}\;$ mean) . Now check what $\;\ker\Phi\;$ is and use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I think I've actually somehow understood it now, thanks a lot even if that isn't the case :) $g_x^{h_k}$ is the inner automorphism $h_k$ of the element $g_x$, ie it's $h_kg_xh_k^{-1}$ The only $x\in K$ that gives $\phi(k) = (e,e)$ is $k=e$, so $ker(\phi) = e$ and thus $K/ker(\phi) = K$ and by the first isomorphism theorem K is isomorphic to the image of $\phi$, which is our semidirect product $G\rtimes H$.

Comment: Great comment, it shows your work, and helps others that are in the process of mastering this topic!